# A question about cyclical order.

Tags: general-topology

am reading through Viro's Elementary topology problem textbook.

In 7.Cx. problem it's asked why cyclic counterclockwise order can't be described as linear order modular cyclic transformation.

But why is that? If a cyclic transformation if a circle is defined as transformation of orders $<_1$ and $<_2$ such that if circle is divided into parts $A$ and $B$ that on parts $A$ and $B$ orders coincide and  $a<_1b$ and $b<_2a$ for any $a$ from  $b$ from $B$, than it seems there is no problem.

So why a cyclic order on a circle can't be described as a linear order modular cyclic transformations? And how then decribe it?